# playwright page.on("pageerror",(exception) does not capture console error

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am using Fixture for Login and that is consumed from test page.
I am running into multiple errors

Both of the below listners are not capturing anything even though i can clearly see error and general message via f12 tools.

1. page.on("pageerror",(exception)
2. page.on("console",(message)

I am not sure, if i am properly assign the page variable, i am suspecting, the page is not the same as page in my webApp, but not sure how to fix it.

*test("Test", async({WebApp,page})*

Login.ts (Fixture)

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';


let userName='XXXXAutoGeneratedUSRFN_1@gmail.com';
let password ='XXXXXXXXXX';

let baseURL = "https://XXXXXXXXXXX/" ;

exports.baseURL = baseURL; ?? I wan to Expose this variable in the consumer, not sure if this is the right way to do it
exports.expect = expect;

exports.test = test.extend({

   WebApp: async ({page}, use) => {

        await page.goto(baseURL);

        // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
        await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/XXXXXXXX/);

        await page.locator('input:has-text("Login")').click();

        //await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle'); // This resolves after 'networkidle'

        //Make sure we are on LoginOrSignUp Tab
        await expect(page).toHaveURL(baseURL + 'LoginOrSignUp',{ timeout: (1000 * 1000) });

        
        //Find Tab(with css = e-tab-text) with text = Login click it
        await page.locator('div[role="toolbar"] >> text=Login').click();
                
        //Find Email text box(#logInEmail) and enter email
        await page.fill("#logInEmail",`${userName}`);
        
        //find password text(#loginInPassword) and enter password
        await page.fill('#loginInPassword', `${password}`);

        await page.locator('#loginSignIn').click();

        //await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle'); // This resolves after 'networkidle'

        await page.waitForURL("https://XXXXXXXXXXX/")

        await use(page)
   },

});
```

----- my test

```
const {test, expect, baseURL,WebApp} = require("./Login");

 
  test.describe("Describe-Test", ()=>{ 

    test.beforeEach(async ({page}) =>{
    console.log("Before Each fired");
    });

    test.use({ 
      geolocation : {latitude:41.74959, longitude: -88.19903},
      permissions :['geolocation'],
      project: 'Mobile Chrome'
    });
  
  
    test("Test", async({WebApp,page}) => {
     
      await test.step("Open Search Page", async () => {

        await WebApp.locator('input:has-text("Get In Line")').click();
      
        await expect(WebApp).toHaveURL(baseURL + 'XXXXXXXXX');
        await expect(WebApp.locator('button', { hasText: 'Search' })).toBeVisible();


      });



      await test.step("Search for Business", async () => {
        
        const PAGE_ERRORS:string[] = [];
        let gpsAvailable:boolean = false;

         //Not working as expected, i do have error, but nothing gets logged here
        page.on("pageerror",(exception) => {
            PAGE_ERRORS.push(exception);
            console.log("Page Error Event Fired");
        });
             
        //not working as expected, i do have messages, but nothing gets logged here
        const CONSOLE_LOG:any[] = [];
        page.on("console",(message) => {
            if(message == "JavaScript: displayMarkersOnGoogleMap Executed")
            {
              gpsAvailable=true;
            }
            CONSOLE_LOG.push({message, type:message.type()});
        });

        console.log(CONSOLE_LOG);

        await WebApp.locator('#searchByCode').fill(`E28E06B4-6434-44FA-812B-D86E2C061BCE`); //Search
      
        if(!gpsAvailable)
        {
          console.log("GPS not available, waiting...");
          await WebApp.waitForTimeout(4000); //this one works, GeoLocation takes some time to return the position
        }
        

        await WebApp.locator('button', { hasText: 'Search' }).click();
    
        await WebApp.locator('button', { hasText: 'GetInLine' }).click();
    
        //Match URL to start with
        await expect(WebApp).toHaveURL(new RegExp('^' + baseURL + 'SelectToken'));

                 
        await WebApp.locator("text='Written Exam' >> input[name='Categoryoptions']" ).click();

           //Get the Token
        await Promise.all([
          WebApp.waitForResponse('**/api/Organization/XXXXXXXXX'),
            //GetinLineApp.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('**/api/Organization/XXXXXXXXXXX') && resp.status() === 200),
            WebApp.locator('button.btn-success', { hasText: 'GetInLine' }).click(),
           
        ]);

        console.log(PAGE_ERRORS);
        expect(PAGE_ERRORS.length).toBe(0);

       // page.locator('button.btn-success', { hasText: 'XXXXXXXX' }).click();
        //await !expect(page.locator('.alert-danger')).toBeVisible();
        //check if success message has been displayed.
        await expect(WebApp.locator('.alert-success')).toContainText('A new Token');
    
      });

    }); //test


  }); //test.describe
```

Comment: Did you ever find any solution? Neither `test.fail()` nor `throw new Error()` seems to cause the test to be marked failed.